# Breaking up an all C# WPF application into XAML for one of its UI controls and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, uielement

This is a broad question, I am aware. However, I have been trying to make a modification in a C# source code  to enable a ToolboxControl UI control's right hand border to respond to a mouse drag.  In other words make the control size bigger by grabbing the right hand boarder and dragging it to the right.  I Have not been successful. So I am thinking if I incorporate a XAML file and create the ToolboxControl in XAML, maybe I would have more control in manipulating the ToolBoxControl.

I dont know how to break up a pure C# WPF code into C# and XAML.

In a nutshell, The problem I am dealing currently is that there is already C# code developed by other developers to perform certain function. I am using the existing C# code  but I believe if I move some of the UI functionality from the C# into a XAML file, I would have a better handle on adding some of the  needed UI features to the original program.

So  you see my problem is I am not starting from scratch. I need to use an existing C# code and break away some UI functionality of it nd put it in a new xaml file. Do you have any ideas about any place that that has been done?

I am looking for any repsonse  that leads me to a conversation thread or a sample.  In other words I dont know where to start from. any useful guidance is apprecaited and would be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/).

At its simplest, you will need to add an invisible (or not) drag handle to the right hand border of your control, then adjust the control size during the drag events raised by that drag handle.

[Here is another article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1) showing a similar concept expanded to an entire diagramming system, which includes the resize behavior you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to define a style for what you are trying to accomplish. I wouldn't worry too much about breaking apart the C# from the XAML as that is a nice to have but not nec

Comment: @kb04sh088 :  Can you please elaboaret on "define a style" ?  I 's appreciate it.